# Only allow a subset of an enum as return value - OR How to get the compiler to alert me ? in C++

Tags: c++, enums

## My Goal

I have multiple functions that will return a **large List of errorcodes**. 
Some functions will use same and distinct errorcodes of the "List of errorcodes"

- for Example:

  - `fun1()` will ONLY return `errorcode1` OR `errorcode2`  (errorcode2 is only used in this function)
  - `fun2()` will ONLY return `errorcode1` OR `errorcode3`  (but errorcode1 is used in both functions)

The desired solution should consider the following points:
    -

- Have a definition what errorcode can be returned by which function
- Get compile error if any function tries to return an errorcode that was not intended for this function
- Whatever the function return or throws must be convertable to int (because these functions will be part of a C API)

## My Approaches

So far I considered to options that use enums but the solutions do not appeal to me

1. Define for each function a separate enum
2. Define one global enum for all function

### Define for each function a separate enum

```
enum errorcodefun1 {errorcode1=1, errorcode2=2};               // OK at least it is expressed what is expected for fun1
errorcodefun1 fun1() {  };  
enum errorcodefun2 {errorcode1_fun2=1, errorcode3_fun2=3  };   // minor problem: not expressing that errorcode1_fun2 is logical same as errorcode1
```

The more functions (which partly use same errorcode) the more code duplication I get.

### Define one enum for all function

```
enum errorcodes {errorcode1=1, errorcode2=2, errorcode3=3};
errorcode fun1() {... } //do not like because I will get no compilation error if it returns errorcode3. Only errorcode1 and errocode2 is intended
errorcode fun2() {... }
```

## My Question

I was thinking about  writing a class that emulates the enum, but so far I see the solution that satisfies all my needs.

Do you have  some suggestions or ideas how to accomplish my goal?

Comment: One global error list would be easier to handle.

Comment: Yes, if I had to decide between both approaches, I would also go for the global error list.

Comment: I think such design (specifying error sets for each and every function) will just lead to the same mess as using throw specs for functions. Just document well (using doxygen or alike), which function will return which error codes in specific situations that it encounters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about going with approach #1 but staying safe and expressing the equivalence of the enum members?

```
enum generic_error {
    ERR_OK,
    ERR_NOMEM,
    ERR_IO,
    ERR_GENERIC
};

enum first_error {
    FIRSTERR_OK = ERR_OK,
    FIRSTERR_NOMEM = ERR_NOMEM
};

enum second_error {
    SECONDERR_OK = ERR_OK,
    SECONDERR_IO = ERR_IO
};

int main()
{
    enum first_error f = FIRSTERR_OK;
    enum second_error s = SECONDERR_OK;
    assert(f == s); // never fires
    return 0;
}
```

Not that this would be particularly good practice, though... If I were you, I would really just opt to have one common error code enumeration.

Comment: This basically answers my question. However, there are 2 minor things a can not accomplish. **1st**: If I have a larger subset of errorcodes that can be returned by multiple function, I would have to assign them one by one to first_error and second_error. **2nd**: Assume we will hide the information of `first_error` and `second_error` from client view. In this case all function need to return generic_error. The definition of first_error and second_error is just to get the help from compiler. For compiler it is enough to have the definition of `first_error` and second_error in translation unit.

Comment: @ToBe Sorry, and what are your questions?

Answer (score -1):

Use bitmasks.

```
enum Code : unsigned int
{
    None = 0,
    SomeError= 1,
    AnotherError = 2,
    YetAnotherError = 4
};

unsigned int valid_error_codes_for_func1 = SomeError | YetAnotherError;
```

Comment: Won't this restrict you to have only 32 error codes (64 for a `long long`)? OP is talking about a **large list** of error codes.

Comment: Yes, of course. It's a simple design for a simple approach. I feel that a design of error handling of lots of different errors based on only returning error codes is inherently not very scalable.

Comment: @Wilbert Not really. Doing it where each error code gets an entire bit dedicated to them isn't scalable, but if you do error codes sanely, you can break up the space of possible codes into regions dedicated to certain components, you can have a list of codes and associated error messages, and you don't get an explosion of types that need to be marshaled between components in different languages. The best error handling I've seen in code I've worked on was in a large collection of plain C applications that used just error codes.

Comment: @Eric Finn This is only possible if only a single error can occur in each function. As soon as you have the potential to have multiple failures, you need to combine errors, which means you need flags (or something more complex like containers).

Comment: @Wilbert I've never seen a function that needed to report more than one simultaneous error. If an error doesn't stop a function from doing its job, it can log it, deal with it, and carry on. If it does stop a function from doing its job, the it shouldn't keep doing its job and encountering further errors. And if the two errors are from tasks that are unrelated to each other, your function is doing two tasks that are unrelated to each other and should be broken up.

Comment: @Eric Finn That will force the client code of the library to do all the hard work, as you cannot really group functions to hide complexity; And if you do, you expose details 'three functions down'. Both ways lead to bad solutions, but I guess that's an inherent problem of using error codes.